# Loading page post data from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to load a single page post data from Facebook. As you may know some posts have IDs like PAGE_ID + '_' + POST_ID and some have just POST_ID. When I have Page_ID and Post_ID  available (I get these IDs from ad creatives), and want to get the post data, I don't know if I should call

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID

or

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID_POST_ID

Is there a normalised way on graph api to get post data? Should I make another request if one of the above fails?

Answer (score 0):

A post_id is a universal unique id in the Facebook Grap. For as answer to your question:

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID

The post_ids have indeed sometimes some logic that is like pageid_postId. But don't think about it. PostId is uuid in Facebook.

And if you have more questions or issues you can easily the GRAP explorer and enter whatever id and check the result:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

And enter the id in the text field after the GET dropdownlist.